# objective c - .m and .a files?

Tags: objective-c

I have a IPhone project and I need to change some code in it. The problem is: this project doesn't have any .m file. I have all header files (.h) and some nib files. I found a .a(?) file and when I took a look in it, it had some code inside, aparently it's some kind of compilated file. Is there any way to de-compile this file?

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.a` file is a compiled static library file (aka *archive*).  It does not contain any source code, only object code for one or more architectures.

What exactly do you need to change?  What are you trying to achieve?  There's almost certainly a better way to do it.  You can use [`ar(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ar.1.html) utility to manipulate archive files, such as by extracting or replacing object files, but I strongly recommend against that unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: I was wrong man. This .a file does not do anything(I deleted it from my project and it's still compiling). But it's still wierd, because I dont have almost any .m file. How can it works? Where are these files? Have you ever seen something like it?

Comment: @Claudio did you figure out how/why the project can compile without it?